# want to Ignore/stop compilation of some framework for simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, compilation

in iOS development, I am facing problem with an SDK which only works in device.
but some of my modules are dependent on it. they give hundreds of error on if i compile it for simulator. but for device it works.

i want those module should not compile at simulator, because other developers who are sharing code with me are not able to run it on simulator.

please let me know if some one has solution or way around for it.

Comment: You have to use weak linking for it ! Here it is :- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use TargetConditionals.h to conditionalize your code for the platform you are on.  You can use the TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR macro for your needs.  Eg:

```
#include <TargetConditionals.h>

#if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#include <SomeDeviceOnlyFramework/SomeDeviceOnlyFramework.h>
#endif
```